# What is the meaning of the gradle and build files looking yellow in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-studio-4.0

It does not appear in any other projects I have, and I dont remember doing anything in particular for this to happen. I'm wondering in what way they affect my project. Can they be deleted? Should they?
[Android build and gradle files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjcAn.png)

Answer (score 0):

these are the files that are auto generated when you build the app.
You can delete them but they will be generated again on the next build